# How to add a Twitter account, not mine, to a Facebook account

Tags: facebook, twitter, account-management, sharing

I have an Admin account on a village Facebook account. Someone has created a Twitter account also for the village. They have suggested that the Twitter posts can be seen on our Facebook page. Is this possible?

Comment: Can't you get the twitter account credentials from them?

Answer (score 1):

You need to link the Twitter account with Facebook so you need the credentials (user/password) of the account to link the page with it. It's a one time process and later password could be changed so no security problems for the Twitter account owner.